# Java Applet not working when another web app with applet is active

Tags: java, applet

I have active web app that uses applet to accessing computer COM ports (printing without prompting user). Everything is working fine until there is another web app that uses applet is active. I don't have access to another apps source code.

The problem is I am very noobish in Java Applet-s and I don't even know what might be the problem. Has anyone encountered this issue, or can anyone at least point me in the right direction, where and what should I be looking at, and/or how this problem can be avoided.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the life-cycle. There are four methods relating to the life-cylce:

- init
- start - page is loaded
- stop - page is unloaded
- destroy

Do all initialisation in `start`, destruction in `stop` and everything should be more encapsulated.
Also do not use `static` objects, and I am even as paranoid to set fields to null when feasible (destroy, stop).